# Angularfire2 & Firestore – retrieve all subcollection content for a collection list

Tags: angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I try to retrieve datas in a `subcollection` based on the key received on the first call.
Basically, I want a list of all my user with the total of one subcollection for each of them.

I'm able to retrieve the data from the first Payload, but not from `pointRef` below

What is the correct way to achieve that?

```
getCurrentLeaderboard() {
    return this.afs.collection('users').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data()
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        const pointRef: Observable<any> = this.afs.collection('users').doc(`${id}`).collection('game').valueChanges()

        const points = pointRef.map(arr => {
          const sumPoint = arr.map(v => v.value)
          return sumPoint.length ? sumPoint.reduce((total, val) => total + val) : ''
        })

        return { id, first_name: data.first_name, point:points };
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to put my code in a comment, but I think it's better formated as a answer.

First you need subscribe your `pointRef` and you can change your code like this.

```
getCurrentLeaderboard() {
    return this.afs.collection('users').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data()
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        const pointRef: Observable<any> = this.afs.object(`users/${id}/game`).valueChanges() // <--- Here

        const pointsObserver = pointRef.subscribe(points => { //<--- And Here         
          return { id, first_name: data.first_name, point:points };
        })
    })
 }
 ....
 //Usage:
 getCurrentLeaderboard.subscribe(points => this.points = points);
```

And if you going to use this function alot, you should start to [denormalize your data](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input @Makah ! Still have an issue with the view. I can display `id` and `first_name` with  `<div *ngFor="let data of points | async">
      {{ (data.id)}}</div>` but {{data.point}} just return an [object] I try make it async, of using json, but I can't see anything here